# Of what use is my code for finding prime numbers of a certain size?

Tags: prime-numbers, safe-prime, multi-prime-rsa

I've developed a bit of Mathematica code that can find primes within a range of numbers. For example, if I wanted all the primes between one million and two million, it could do that. Of what use is this code I invented ?

The only thing I could think of was that if one wanted to find two primes of a certain size for cryptography keys.

And the code could be used to test a specific number for primality, quickly.

And with the addition of code, it could be made to search for primes of a certain format, like safe primes.

I just invented this last week

Copy the following into Mathematica, select all, right-click on Convert To, choose StandardForm.

`N[Sum[2/10^((n*(Floor[c/n] + 1) - c)*s), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ c]]}] + Sum[ 2/(10^((n*(Floor[c/n] + 1) - c)*s)* (10^(ns) - 1)), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ c]]}] + Sum[2/(10^((o^2 - o - c) s)*(10^(o*s) - 1)), {o, Floor[Sqrt[c]] + 1, max}], ((max + 1)^2 - c)*s]; AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[ Position[Partition[ RealDigits[%][[1]], s, s, -1], {(0) .., 2}]]] + c
-end
c=crossover s=spacing`

The crossover is the number which you want to surpass. The spacing is difficult to determine, so I'll say that in general, if you use a number which is equal to the number of digits of the max^2, you should be safe. So for all primes up to $100^2 = 10000$, that is five digits, so use a 5 for the spacing. Follow this rule and you should be safe.

For those who are wondering, the code is based on a bigger structure of numbers formed by the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: In Mathematica, RandomPrime[{$i_\text{min}$,$i_\text{max}$}] gives a pseudorandom prime number in the range {$i_\text{min}$,$i_\text{max}$}.

Comment: `PrimeQ` is also of interest.

Comment: I am not a Mathematica user, so I might be jumping to conclusions. However I strongly suspect it is possible to restructure your code to make it more readable. As for performance, how quickly would your code be able to find all the safe primes in a range such as $2^{8192}\pm 2^{28}$?

Comment: @kasperd , I might be able to do that. That's a larger range of numbers than I've ever tried before though. Might take a day.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to say that your code is likely to have essentially zero use.

Primes used for cryptography (e.g., RSA), are on the order of 2,048 and 4,096 bits of length, or respectively roughly 616 and 1,233 *digits* long. Algorithms already exist to rapidly find (random) primes of this size, and unless you've broken new ground in number theory, your approach is slower.

Additionally, the general trend lately is moving away from systems like RSA towards elliptic-curve based cryptosystems which have no need for the generation of primes.

Comment: RSA *moduli* today are 2048 bits and up; the two prime factors are half the modulus size. In addition to time, if this code like a standard sieve would need e.g. 2^512 bits of memory, that's not only more than you can fit on any single computer it's hugely more than you can fit on this planet.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Or even in this universe...

Comment: @Stephen Touset , Actually it would be fairly easy for me to find all the primes between 616 digits and 1233 digits. It wouldn't be rapidly but it would find them all.

Comment: @user24719 "it wouldn't be rapid" is an understatement, there physically wouldn't be enough energy in the entire universe to carry out the computation.

Comment: Nor enough storage capacity to record them all.

Comment: Also Elliptic curve crypto needs an algorithm for generation of primes (of course smaller bits than in the RSA case). The elliptic curves are defined over a finite field of the form ${\bf F}_p$ (and not always of the form ${\bf F}_{2^n}).$ I would say that the current trend is to move to cryptosystems that are quantum resistant (and the elliptic curve based crtyptosystems  do not belong in this case).

Comment: @111 Yes, the finite field is over a prime number, but neither the key generation nor the computations for key agreement or signature generation / verification requires the calculations of prime number. Nobody in their right mind would generate their own domain parameters on a regular basis. So the text in the answer is mostly correct. There is no trend yet to move to cryptosystems that are quantum resistant either, I haven't seen a single one being *deployed*; there is just a lot of research.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Yes, that's true, when we first initialize the system we generate a prime number (but the same is true in RSA). For the second part of your comment, there is at least one post quantum primitive that google tried to implement it (security.googleblog.com/2016/07/…)

Comment: @111 No, the key generation for RSA requires the generation of (at least) two primes. The key generation of ECC **doesn't** require the generation of primes. The ECC parameters are a prerequisite and are not part of the key generation. Conversely, no primes are part of the configuration of RSA (unless you count the small, static prime that is commonly used for the public exponent).

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes You mean that I will choose a specific elliptic curve and a specific prime, say for ECDSA and I won't choose "my elliptic curve" and my own prime. But, this is not always the case, for instance see http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/ecc-workshop-2015/papers/session1-miele-paper.pdf, where in this case you have to generate a prime.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Also, something that I can not understand in your comment " The key generation of ECC doesn't require the generation of primes" it is something that in practice we do, but is not prohibited and surely not wrong if someone carefully selects the Elliptic curve and the prime.

Comment: Yeah, OK, you can create your own domain parameters. It's not something that is performed often; I'd say that it is about as common as asymmetric quantum safe crypto. I'm sure it exists and is used though. Lets conclude this discussion, shall we?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes sure